# Why && better than -a in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, testing, manpage

I've read `man test` and found:

> NOTE: Binary -a and -o are inherently ambiguous.  Use 'test EXPR1 &&
>   test EXPR2' or 'test EXPR1 || test EXPR2' instead.

Can someone explain what ambiguously in `-a` and `-o`?

English is not my native language. As I understood, Kevin Braunsdorf and Matthew Bradburn (authors of this man page) advice us to use `&&` instead of `-a` just because `-a` could be used as a key in another binaries, because `-a` could have different possible meanings.

So, `-a` is not associated with `logical AND` when we use `test`. It's not clear for someone, so people thinking like: "Hmm, what is that key? I don't know, not sure it is `logical AND`, I must visit `man`..."

The only reason I could find is that code with `&&` is easier to read for people than code with `-a` (just an example):

With -a:

```
if [ -f "${my_var_with_filename}" -a -n "${my_another_array_var_with_filename[2]}" -o -r /just/path/to/file ]
then
...
fi
```

Same with &&:

```
if [ -f "${my_var_with_filename}" ] && [ -n "${my_another_array_var_with_filename[2]}" ] || [ -r /just/path/to/file ]
then
...
fi
```

As for me, both examples are syntactically complex, and it's hard to read bash code with multiple conditions, variables, array variables and logical operators.

So, my questions are:

1. Do you agree with that `-a` and `-o` in `test` are "inherently ambiguous"?
2. In multiple conditions, do you use `-a(-o)` or `&&(||)`?
3. Someone has arguments to unequivocally name `-a` and `-o` "ambiguous"? Or it's just authors' opinion? Should they advice us to use `&&` instead of `-a` based only on their opinion in man page?

Comment: an other less known difference is the side effects: `test EXPR1 -a EXPR2` will always evaluate both EXPR1 and EXPR2, while `test EXPR1 && test EXPR2` will, like in C language, evaluate EXPR2 only if EXPR1 was true. When EXPR1 and EXPR2 include results from other commands, side effects can matter

Answer (score 5):

Let's stick with strict POSIX, with the extension that `-a` represents logical AND. Now, consider the command

```
test "$1" -a "$2"
```

You might think this will test that both `$1` and `$2` are non-empty strings. But you would be wrong. If `$1 == "!"`, then you have the command

```
test ! -a "$2"
```

which fails because `-a` is not a supported unary operator.

(This is adapted from the example given in the POSIX specification itself.)

---

If this is actually `bash`, it gets worse. `-a` *is* a valid unary operator, so now you are testing if the file named by `$2` does *not* exist.

Answer (score 2):

According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), `[ -f file1 -a -f file2 ]` is unspecified behavior. Let alone much longer `-a`/`-o` constructs.

```
SYNOPSIS:

  test [expression]
  [ expression ]

OPERANDS:

... ...

In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments
presented to test:

0 arguments:

    Exit false (1).

1 argument:

    Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.

2 arguments:

      - If $1 is '!', exit true if $2 is null, false if $2 is not null.

      - If $1 is a unary primary, exit true if the unary test is true,
        false if the unary test is false.

      - Otherwise, produce unspecified results.
```

```
3 arguments:

      - If $2 is a binary primary, perform the binary test of $1 and $3.

      - If $1 is '!', negate the two-argument test of $2 and $3.

      - If $1 is '(' and $3 is ')', perform the unary test of $2. On
        systems that do not support the XSI option, the results are
        unspecified if $1 is '(' and $3 is ')'.

      - Otherwise, produce unspecified results.

4 arguments:

      - If $1 is '!', negate the three-argument test of $2, $3, and $4.

      - If $1 is '(' and $4 is ')', perform the two-argument test of $2
        and $3.On systems that do not support the XSI option, the results
        are unspecified if $1 is '(' and $4 is ')'.

      - Otherwise, the results are unspecified.   

>4 arguments:

    The results are unspecified.
```

Answer (score -2):

1. While the `test` binary has the -a and -o flags, it is not common. Even within the test command itself, [-a is ambiguous](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html) since it can be used to both check if a file exists or represent the binary AND operator.
2. Use && and || for binary AND and binary OR. They are more common and formalized as a standard with the C language.
3. See my response to your first question. Even within the `test` command itself, -a can be ambiguous; use && and || instead.

Comment: Referring to the C language standard isn't really useful, since shell `&&` and `||` have *equal* precedence, in contrast to the C versions of the operators.